# How to make my sprite Jump? (XNA, C#)

Tags: c#, xna, sprite

I've been working on a simple platformer game using XNA. I have been having some trouble working out a good jumping algorithm. After getting rid of the messy half done versions of the jumping algorithm all I have left is.

```
if (keystate.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
{
    spritePosition.Y = spritePosition.Y - 10;
}
```

I realise this is a very unsophisticated start but any tips would be great. I'm a self taught programmer so some terminology might be lost on me, I tend to find looking at actual code the best way to learn. Thanks.

Comment: You should check out http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you jump (physically) you are adding an amount to your Y velocity vector, not to your position vector.  Moving your position by 10 means you're just teleporting upward 10 ticks.

Try adjusting velocity, then letting your main loop change the position.  And remember acceleration downward from gravity!

Edit: Added link from comment below to physics tutorial.  [rodedev.com/tutorials/gamephysics](http://rodedev.com/tutorials/gamephysics)

Comment: Okay, so I've changed it so that it uses the velocity vector instead and It's letting me fly upwards, so now I need to try and make a jump limit. How might I achieve that?

Comment: What, in real life, prevents you from flying upwards?

Comment: Well, gravity. I only fly upwards while I'm pressing the "W" key and gravity brings my sprite back to the ground when I've stopped pressing it. I need some way of making the program just take in a single tap of the "W" key and then send the sprite up to a predetermined height

Comment: I'd say that the only time you should be able to jump, and the only time the program should do anything on a press of W, is when your sprite is "on the ground."  I imagine you'd have to keep track of that, probably with a boolean.  e.g., char.IsOnGround

Comment: I have collision detection already in so it might be something like this?  If keystate.IsKeyDown(Keys.W)) and sprite is on ground then velocity.y = -10? But then it would immediatly stop the moment it left the ground :/ I think that is what I've been having most trouble with

Comment: Actually, I think you're on the right track.  If on ground and W press, add Y velocity.  If not on ground ignore W press and apply gravitational force to Y velocity, then apply Y velocity to Y position.  Try running through this tutorial: http://www.rodedev.com/tutorials/gamephysics/

Comment: I've got to go and catch a bus now but thank you very much for all the help :]

Comment: It really helps talking it through with someone

Comment: Glad to help.  Reach out on game dev for more help.  http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
{
    // your code here
}
```

It will make it so that every time the player presses `W`, they will only go until they can press `W` again. You can always set **Rate of Jump** and make it so that they can only jump once every so and so seconds.

Comment: Is this case sensitive?